# CollectionView items are hidden behind top bar

Tags: ios, swift, chat, collectionview

I have a messaging application, the problem is that the first messages are not visible, when I drag the collection view to see the top messages I can see them but when I release the finger, the collection view jumps back, hiding the first 5 messages that are at the top of the screen

[image]

As we can see from the image there is a message (actually are 5 messages at the top), however I have to drag the collection view to peek those messages. I thought that the size of the collection view is actually larger that the screen, however both the `collectionView.frame.height` and the `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` have the same height, is that ok? .
Here's the code that I use to setup the collection view:

```
 /// Function that configures the ChatViewController collection view
    private func configureCollectionView() {
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = Theme.current.chatGeneralBackground
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

        // Register the chat cell and the loading cellx`
        collectionView?.register(ChatCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: chatCellIdentifier)
        collectionView?.register(LoadingCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: loadingCellIdentifier)

        // Initialize the original height of the collection view
        collectionViewOriginalHeight = collectionView.frame.height
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 7.0, all views automatically go behind navigation bars, toolbars and tab bars to provide what Apple calls "context".

For example, if you don't want a view controller to go behind any bars, use this in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)       
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = [] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the problem with constraints, if you are using custom navigation bar top constraints should be in reference to it. If using default navigation controller, you might need to give the top constraint to 44 from safe area.

However `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` consists of complete screen including the top navigation bar and 20 px of status bar. For collectionView.frame.height you need to minus these values.